# Given an input of shape $(3, 32, 32)$, which is convolved with a $(3 \times 3)$ kernel, how do I calculate the FLOPS?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, filters, convolutional-layers, computational-complexity, flops

I have an input tensor of shape $\mathbf{(3, 32, 32)}$ consisting of 3 channels, 16 rows, and 16 columns. I want to convolve the input tensor using $\mathbf{(3 \times 3)}$ kernel/filter. How can I calculate the required **FLOPs**?

Comment: FLOPs required to compute it

Comment: First, do you know what a FLOP is?

Comment: Floating point operations

Comment: And do you know how to calculate the output? If you know how to calculate the output, you should be able to count the FLOPs in the calculation.

Comment: I don't know how to. That's why I asked the question

Comment: How many output channels?

Comment: It will be the same as the input. Three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each output pixel channel is a 3x3x3 filter, so 27 inputs which get multiplied by 27 weights and then added together. This is 27 FMA (fused-multiply-add) operations, or 27 multiply operations and 26 additions. I believe all modern devices implement FMA.

The number of output pixel channels is 30x30x3 = 2700 (as a 3x3 kernel shaves off one pixel on each edge) and each one takes 27 operations to calculate. So that's 72900 operations in total.